# If $U \neq W$, then $U \cap W$ is a one-dimensional subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space with $\dim(V) = 3$. Let $U, W$ be vector subspaces of dimension two in $V$ (i.e. planes through the origin). How do I see that if $U \neq W$, then $U \cap W$ is a one-dimensional subspace?

Answer (score 3):

Since $U\ne W$ it is $3=\dim (U+W).$ Now

$$3=\dim (U+W)=\dim U+\dim W-\dim (U\cap W)=4-\dim(U\cap W),$$

from where $\dim (U\cap W)=1.$

Answer (score 0):

$dim U\cap W\leq 2$ if it be equal to $2$ then $U\cap W=U=W$ contradiction with  $U \neq W$ and since dimension $V=3$ then cannot be $dim U\cap W=0$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The intersection of the planes through the origin is a line through the origin, i.e. the one dimensional subspace you were looking for