# If $L \neq M$ then $L + M$ is a two-dimensional vector subspace of $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This is a followup question to my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1447175/if-u-neq-w-then-u-cap-w-is-a-one-dimensional-subspace).

Let $L$, $M$ be vector subspaces of dimension one in $V$ (i.e. lines through the origin), where $V$ is a vector space with $\dim(V) = 3$. How do I see that if $L \neq M$ then $L + M$ is a two-dimensional vector subspace of $V$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Use $\dim(L+M)=\dim(L)+\dim(M)-\dim(L\cap M)$, and that $\dim(L\cap M)<\dim L$ if $L\not\subseteq M$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Intuitively it works like this: the linear combination of the points in two different lines (through the origin) results in all the points of a plane (through the origin), i.e. dim 2. If the lines are the same, the linear combination is the line itself i.e dim 1.